# Can I use IPs assigned to virtual network interfaces in a bash script?

Tags: linux, networking, bash

I'm wondering if it's possible to dynamically read in the IP addresses of network interfaces for use in a bash script.  Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
MYPUBLICIP= get_eth0_address
MYPRIVATEIP= get_eth0:0_address
```

- How would I go about this?
- Is it possible to distinguish between eth0 and the virtual eth0:0?

*[Background]
I'm trying to write a script to apply various rules to iptables for a set of VPSs. I'm trying to avoid having to fiddle around with the individual IPs of each machine.*

Comment: You should be able to make your own function, using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452917/get-network-interface-information. Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474172/how-to-find-network-interface-name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ip` will always return all the address records for a physical interface, even if you specify a virtual one.

`ifconfig` let's you specify a single interface, but is a bit more annoying to parse:

```
ifconfig eth0:0 |awk -F':| ' '/inet addr/{print $13}'
```

**EDIT**

The `ip` way can be managed with more selective awk, of course:

```
ip -o -4 addr sh |awk '/eth0:0/{print $4}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
ip -4 -o addr show dev eth0 | sed 's/\// /g' | awk '{print $4}'
```

should give you the bare ip address of the relevant interface.

Comment: Interesting - I'll have a play around with that. Thanks.

Comment: It seems it returns both IP addresses assigned to the interface whether I use eth0 or eth0:0.  If the order is guaranteed though, perhaps I can just select the right one from the string.